# Unable to access JSON Element in Javascript via Object.property

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am unable to access a simple JSON Element from a JSON Structure that looks like:

```
{
"ACTION": "AA",
"MESSAGE": "Customer: 30xxx Already Approved on 2017/01/01"
}
```

I get the data in JSON Format but when i do data.ACTION or data.MESSAGE i get Undefined as the output.

By doing case sensitive also, its not working( Image attached )
[image]

```
var url = base + query;
var getJSON = function (url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', url, true);
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
        xhr.onload = function () {
            var status = xhr.status;
            if (status == 200) {
                resolve(xhr.response);
            } else {
                reject(status);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    });
};

getJSON(url).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data); //Getting JSON Data                   
    var output = JSON.stringify(data);
    var obj = JSON.parse(output.replace(/ 0+(?![\. }])/g, ' '));
    console.log(output);
    console.log(obj.message); //Here getting UNDEFINED                    

}, function (status) { //error detection....
    alert('Something went wrong.');
});

Console:
{"ACTION":"AA","MESSAGE":"Customer No. 0000030332 Already Approved On 20170113"}

stringify returns the following
{\"ACTION\":\"AA\",\"MESSAGE\":\"Customer No. 0000030332 Already Approved On 20170113\"}"
```

Comment: Why all the stringify/parse thing? `JSON.parse(data)` should suffice.

Comment: javascript is case sensitive, it's `obj.MESSAGE`

Comment: Data is already coming in JSON Format. I was just testing it out. data and obj return the same JSON output( mentioned in the top of the post ).

If you do JSON.Parse on a Parsed data it gives error.

Comment: You don't need all the parsing, and the JS is *case sensitive*. Just simple use `data.MESSAGE`

Comment: For future reference, you can quickly check what calls for what in an object by using this simple and quick script: **`for (var x in obj) console.debug('obj.'+x, "\t=\t", data[x])`** Just replace the 2 `obj`'s with the name of your object, in this case `data`, which would look like: `for (var x in data) console.debug('data.'+x, "\t=\t", data[x])`

Comment: @SpYk3HH thanks for the info. I have data.0 = { , data.1 = " ..each letter is decomposed. But, i don't know how it will help me in this case

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong with your data, or not getting what you expect. If your `data` return is what you say it is, then you should see: `data.ACTION  =  AA` as the first line. Are you sure you're JSON encoding it before sending it back to the browser ( i mean on the backend )

Comment: Also, I see you reinvented the wheel. At first I thought you were using jQuery's getJSON, but you wrote your own, why? Look here -> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: `$.getJSON(url, function(data) { console.log(data.MESSAGE); })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED. I first thought the error was due to parsing, given the print. -.-

Solution:
When you print the output, `obj` it's still a string, not an object. So it is OK at that point.

Your "undefined" property `message` should be replaced by `MESSAGE`.
Instead of `console.log(obj.message);` just use `console.log(obj.MESSAGE);`

Also. An example of parsing JSON:

```
var myJson = '{"ACTION":"AA","MESSAGE":"Customer No. 0000030332 Already Approved On 20170113"}';
console.log(myJson);   // This prints the literal string  
console.log(JSON.parse(myJson)); // this prints an "object"
```

Comment: But if he's using `getJSON`, then it's already parsed, if passed correctly by the backend controller. Might be an issue of not properly using `json_encode` or something of the sort.

Comment: Looked like data was not proper JSON from Server

Answer (score 1):

`obj.message` property is not defined and when you try to get the property which is not defined on an object, you get `undefined`.

Javascript is case sensitive. You should try `obj.MESSAGE` instead to get the property value. Also, to check if a property exists on an object you can make use of `object.hasOwnProperty([propName])` method to check if a property exists on a object or not.

**EDIT 1:** Try running the following code snippet. JSON data string is parsed before accessing the property.

```js
var jsonString = "{\"ACTION\":\"AA\",\"MESSAGE\":\"Customer No. 0000030332 Already Approved On 20170113\"}";

var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
console.log(obj.MESSAGE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But still not working. I have added picture for reference

Comment: Edited the answer, please check.

Answer (score 1):

`data` already is a JSON string, there's no need to `JSON.stringify` it (which returns a string with a JSON-encoded string literal). Parsing it into `output` only leads to a string again, which has no properties. You should use

```
console.log(data);
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(obj);
obj.MESSAGE = obj.MESSAGE.replace(/ 0+(?![\. }])/g, ' ');
```

(notice the proper casing of the property name)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
var jsonObject = data.data;
console.log(jsonObject.ACTION)
```